# How could I locate the pointers in a different section from constants in a C module?

Tags: c, gcc

I have in a C file a constant and a pointer to a struct. I use a `pragma` directive to locate these constants in a special area of the flash memory.
The problem is that the pointers are locating also in the flash memory. And I have an exception error (`Cache Writeback Error`) and I am going into a trap.

I use the `Higtec-gcc v4.6.4.0` Compiler.

How can I fix it? Should I change the linker script or do you have another suggestion?

Please consider that I have more than 50 Files with the same content and some files are exported from Simulink.

See the code:

```
#include "cal.h"
#pragma section .rodata.Sec_CALIB

const volatile struct_type cal_struct = { 1000, 2000, 1000, 150, 1500, 50, {
50, 50, 100, 100 }, { 0, 1000, 2000 };
const volatile struct_type *ptr_cal_struct = &cal_struct;
```

Comment: Beware; `volatile` rarely *actually* means what you think it does and in *most* cases is *not* what you really want. You should usually stay away from it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl looks like a valid use of `volatile` here.

Comment: @YSC *Maybe*. I find it *extremely* hard to judge that, given how underspecified `volatile` is in the standard. In any case, all I'm doing is advicing caution.

Comment: Agree with @YSC. I do not see any wrong in use volatile. 'volatile' is  just a flag to tell the compiler: 'Do not apply optimizations to this'.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. When do you get the error? When you get the pointer of the struct?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Have you ever even written a program that's storing data in flash? If not, I suggest you keep your bad, misleading advice to yourself. Failing to use volatile here will result in a complete garbage program in case the flash is updated - which is the whole point with keeping it as a separate segment like this.

Comment: @Lundin no need to be so hostile.

Comment: @pop rock How do you know that the pointer ends up in flash? If it does, that means that the linker shows everything after the pragma into flash, no matter const qualifier. Which is a bit unusual behavior - on most toolchains you would have to declare the pointer as `const volatile struct_type* const` to make it end up in flash. Probably there's some "pragma default" command you need to use, I don't know your toolchain.

Comment: @Lundin I saw it in map file and when the software is running is going in the trap with the error Cache Writeback.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yeah you clearly misunderstand it, since it is a  fundamental language feature for any embedded systems programming. Without it, it is not possible to write hardware-related, optimized C code. So "don't use volatile" is about as helpful advice as "don't use variables".

Comment: Is the pointer constant (not changing values) or is the pointer pointing to constant data?  If the pointer is constant, the compiler may be placing the pointer into the read-only segment (with all the other constants).  You may want something like: `struct_type const * const ptr_cal_struct;`, read pointer declarations from right to left.  Having many years programming Flash devices, I don't see why you need the pointer as `volatile` or its contents as `volatile`.  Declare `volatile` if the hardware or other functions will change the data.

Comment: I think you need an empty `#pragma section` to set compiler output back to the default section.

Comment: It may be better (or at least a more modern usage of gcc) to use `__attribute__ ((section (".rodata.Sec_CALIB")))` before the `=` initializer of `cal_struct`.